Using Timeshift to restore old apps' and settings
Like others, I experienced issues with Ubuntu 24.04 after upgrading in late August.
These issues included slow bootup, failure to accept some system updates like the new 6.8.0-45 kernel and eventual failure to boot at all.
I had Timeshift set up so I could restore. But for some reason the only 22.04 snapshot I have is from 2022 so there is no sense in trying to rollback to that as so many apps were added since then, settings changed, etc.
I have a few snapshots of 24.04 but getting these in is difficult and faulty (blue background screen rather than usual purple theme, limited Settings menu, etc) and I think that even if I succeed in getting the system to a previous "workable" state, it will simply have the same update issue as I had before the bootup failure.
So now I am looking at just doing a fresh install of 24.04 that uses 6.8.0-45 kernel and seems to be stable and updatable when I use it on the Live USB.
But that is just the system and not the many applications plus associated settings. Is there any way that I can safely extract the app' last usable state from my Timeshift snapshot ?

yo may find this itsFOSS article useful

@graham The article on itsFOSS is good but overlooks this issue. Refer to the YT video linked in my answer below.

Are you planning to restore from the backup of Ubuntu 22.04 or 24.04? Restoring apps from 22.04 may break your system. Traditional Linux apps (that are installed by sudo apt install ... depend on libraries that are already installed. This is called "dependency". If you mix and match OS and apps of different versions, you may get dependency hell!

I was only trying to restore from 24.04.1 - as my only 22.04 snapshot is too old - but this was only providing me with the same old faulty 24.04 upgrade from 22.04. So now I'm after doing a clean fresh new install and doing what I can to restore old app settings and data. A proper screw-up by Canonical.

Apparently, according to this Timeshift video on YouTube from 7:16, it is possible to select those folders/files that you want to restore from a given snapshot.
Basically it's only a case of selecting the snapshot, clicking on Browse at the top of the Timeshift window, finding the folders/files in question and copy-and-pasting them to the new location on the reinstalled system's file system.
Working so far for my Thunderbird data and config files - the major worry.
I may have issues with things like Sublime Text plugins and tuning Eclipse/IntelliJ but that's just work.

good luck with that

Are you doubting this shortcut procedure, @graham ?
